Mesh flaws don't allow proper texturing in FBX imported into Blender
I'm importing an FBX file into Blender and I get these flaws.
I can't get a uniform texture when I try to apply textures to these meshes.
What could be the problem here?




Process: I draw the cable harnesses in Inventor, then I convert STEP file to FBX in Fusion, then import FBX to Blender.

It looks as if you may have inverted normals but we'd need to see your Blend file to confirm that.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.
